# Lorenzini's “Invitation to arithmetic geometry”, 2nd exercise

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

I have some trouble trying to prove that

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{2+i}{5}\right]\cap \mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{Z}
\end{equation}

which is the second exercise of Dino Lorenzini's "An invitation to arithmetic geometry".

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please give more details about the "trouble" you are having "trying to prove" the statement.  Where, exactly, are you stuck?

Comment: @Tommy1234 Why do you want to draw more attention to this question? Is the existing answer not satisfying to you?

Comment: @Suzet Here $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{2+i}{5}\right]$ is supposed to be the subring of of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ generated by 1 and $\frac{2+i}{5}$, namely $$  \mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{2+i}{5}\right] = \left\{a_0 + a_1\left(\frac{2+i}{5}\right) + \ldots + a_n\left(\frac{2+i}{5}\right)^n \ \bigg| \ a_i\in\mathbb{Z}\ \text{ and } n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}, $$ so I don't think the current answer is correct.

Answer (score -2):

First of all I'm apologized for my bad English.

Called $x=\frac{2+i}{5}$ and defines $\mathbb{Z}[x]=\{a+bx \vert a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

Observe what $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[x] $ with $ b=0$ then

$\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[x] \cap \mathbb{Q} $.

Now take $ z \in  \mathbb{Z}[x] \cap \mathbb{Q} $ then  $ z=a+bx$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $ z \in \mathbb{Q}$ so the only way to belong to both sets is that $ z=a $.

therefore it has to be $ \mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}[x] \cap \mathbb{Q} $.

Comment: I am not sure why $\mathbb{Z}[x]=\{a+bx \mid a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}$, I mean, $x$ is indeed an algebraic element of degree over $\mathbb{Z}$, but $K[x]$ is a vector space o degree 2 when $K$ is a field. Is not there any problem to consider $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank 2?